# Is there disagreement about reopening the tornadoes question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I've edited [the tornadoes question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29391/what-good-do-tornadoes-do/29427#29427) for writing clarity and to be more clearly on-topic, without, I think, changing what the OP meant to ask.

Any other reasons not to re-open it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dronz, I consider that your edit was a good improvement. I took your edit because the title was straight to the point but I could have either rolled back to KeithS's edit or made my own.

The original question was unclear and misleading. Several people made complains in the comments and downvoted the question because of this. 
Although I understand it's the user's post, everyone is free to edit it and improvements to the post should be kept as long as they do not change the meaning of the question.

We prefer to have questions that are clear and thus answerable by the community. Misleading question might have answers that are off the track.
Bad question tend to get donwovoted and with enough time, there is the risk of deletion by the system. We don't want that if the question has already several answers and a potential to gather a few others. If the question is salvageable, we should try to keep it so the answers have not been for nothing.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. That all makes sense to me and is what I thought. Often there are questions that are written so that people think they are bad questions or off-topic, but they really are interesting to world-builders if taken as such. I posted this question here because I think with my edit, it looks on-topic, so I would think it shouldn't be listed any more as on hold (off topic). The site's prompts were to edit the question if salvageable, but I don't know if it's still marked off-topic because I was also supposed to flag it, or if someone still thinks it's off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently:

1. The original asker disagrees with your edit.
2. The original asker is satisfied with the existing answers.

From that, I'd say that if you want the revised question answered, you should ask your own.  If you were just trying to be helpful, the original asker has pretty clearly indicated that your changes were unhelpful to him.

I actually think that @Vincent was wrong to revert to your changes.  If your version is better, then someone else should ask it.  The original asker shouldn't have to work with a question with which he disagrees.  If the question as asked was bad, it could be closed and then possibly deleted.

Oh, and since the original asker isn't likely to say it, thanks for trying to make the site better.  Even if it's not working out as you hoped, others may appreciate your efforts more in the future.

Comment: Hmm. Ok thanks for trying to explain. I think the OP is a little confused, as the wording was pretty off, and I see his comment now that he thinks a question shouldn't be a sentence but a title... which ok I guess I don't care. It just seems to me there is a decent question, at least as I reworded it and had answered it (note he accepted the answer I gave before it was put on hold for being off topic). Ah well.